# netlogo patch set as chess board style

Tags: netlogo

how can I set al of patches like chess board. one white than black?

```
ask patches [if ...... [set pcolor white]
             if .......[set pcolor black]]
```

could you say is it the right way or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming your world is already 8x8 patches and the patches are default black:

```
ask patches [if pxcor mod 2 = pycor mod 2 [set pcolor white]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an 8x8 world

```
to setup
      ask patches [
        ifelse pxcor mod 2 = pycor mod 2 
      [set pcolor white]
      [set pcolor black]
      ]

    end
```